# How do I parse the accounts in a versioned Transaction?

Tags: versionedtransactions

Say I have given a versioned transaction and I want to get the accounts in the same format my smart contract will see it in. How do I do this?

Edit: I've tried the below, but this always gives me `Error: Failed to get account keys because address table lookups were not resolved`, which makes sense since this is a synchronous method and I didn't fetch the LUTs onchain anywhere else.

```
const allAccs = transaction.message.getAccountKeys().keySegments().reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. If our transaction is `tx`, we can just do:

```
const LUTs = (await Promise.all(transaction.message.addressTableLookups
    .map((acc) => conn.getAddressLookupTable(acc.accountKey))))
    .map((lut) => lut.value).filter((val) => val !== null) as AddressLookupTableAccount[];
const allAccs = transaction.message.getAccountKeys({ addressLookupTableAccounts: LUTs })
    .keySegments().reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
    const tx = await connection.getParsedTransaction(
    "3PF85bjev6h7ydKyKpwLyw9R7jq2A9PdzRjtuhbzjKXgLZgdFcXWKZK89KSdes2qu4kWsBXgk6srsHDFpnfEoCEH",
    {
        maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0
    }
);
console.log(tx.transaction.message.accountKeys);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I already solved my issue in my answer below. Additionally, the tx hasn't been executed yet, so I can't use `getParsedTransaction`. I didn't say it had, but tbf I also didn't say it hadn't :)