# What are exactly Account Key Indexes?

Tags: web3.js

I'd like to create a parser of transactions to play around with solana web3.

I've seen that VersionedTransaction contains message & signatures.

The MessageV0 contains a bunch of publicKeys inside the "staticAccountKeys" as well as addressTableLookups and compiledInstructions.

I'm finding it hard to reconstruct what a tx is doing based ont he instructions.

From my "reverse engineering" stuff i've noticed that if an instruction looks like this:

```
{
programIdIndex: 17,
accountKeyIndexes: [1,2],
data: Uint8Array(8) [
  3, 59, 0, 0,
  0,  0,  0, 0
]
```

}
then it means that the instruction is meant for the program having pubkey equal to staticAccountKeys[17].

This program will receive the 8 bytes 3,59,0,0,0,0,0,0. but what i dont understand is accountKeyIndexes (in this case 1,2). What are these suppoused to represent?

Answer (score 2):

Transactions are serialized in such a way to minimize size. One of the ways this happens is by minimizing re-use of accounts. This means if we have an instruction that takes the accounts `ABC` and `DEF`, we don't attach these to the instruction directly. Instead, we have a global account array for the whole transaction consisting of `staticAccountKeys` and any potentially resolved LUTs. Then, when we want to say that our instruction references accounts `ABC` and `DEF` we provide the index of these two accounts in our global array. This is what `accountKeyIndexes` refers to, your instruction takes the accounts at index 1 and 2. (That way if two instructions want account `ABC` we don't need 32 bytes of space for each, instead we need 1x 32 bytes for the account and 2x 1 byte for the index).

PS: To be able to fully parse the instruction you'll need to reconstruct this entire global array which includes resolving LUTs. [This question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/how-do-i-parse-the-accounts-in-a-versioned-transaction) explains how this is done.

Comment: If you're interested, this article gives a good overview of the format of VersionedTransactions overall: https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html